# Javascript Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am creating a web app that uses the Fullcalendar plugin. The part I am stuck on is trying to obtain the date is selected when a user clicks on a cell. For example a user clicks on 07/02/2018, a popup window appears and inside that window is the date (variable).

This is what I have gotten so far but for some reason I can get the date variable to appear in the popup window. Am I referencing it wrong?

**This is the dayClick function:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    $('.dayClickWindow').show();
      var date=date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      alert(date)
},
```

**This is the popup window contained in the body:**

```
    <div class="dayClickWindow">
            <script>document.write(date.dayClick())</script>
           <a href="/test" class="btn" role="dayClickClose">Close</a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date from the dayClick callback function is only available inside the function. So your document.write won't know what `date` you are talking about.

What you can do is include a `<span>` in your div and populate the span with the date when the user clicks the day.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      var dateFormatted = date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      $('#dayClickDateSpan').text(dateFormatted);
      $('.dayClickWindow').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div class="dayClickWindow hidden">
  <span id="dayClickDateSpan"></span>
  <a href="/test" class="btn" role="dayClickClose">Close</a>
</div>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I needed it to, thank you sir!